# c# Rich text Format error in code

Tags: c#, escaping, richtextbox, rtf

hoping you can help

I have the following code

```
List<string> comconfig = populate.resolveconfig(_varibledic, populate.GetVaribles[0].Substring(populate.GetVaribles[0].IndexOf("=") + 1)); //get the aray of strings
            string config = ""; //create a empty otput string
            config = @"\rtf1\ansi\deff0\deftab240 {\fonttbl {\f000 Monaco;} {\f001 Monaco;} } {\colortbl \red255\green255\blue255; \red000\green000\blue000; \red255\green255\blue255; \red000\green000\blue000; }";
            config = config + @"\f96\fs20\cb3\cf2 \highlight1\cf0 "; // assigned rtf header to output string 

            foreach (var strings in comconfig) //loop though array adding to output string
            {
                config = config + strings + @"\par ";
            }
            config = config + "}"; //close of RTF code
```

So trying to create a RTF string that I can later display. comconfig is an array of strings with some RTF mark up for highlighting and stuff.

trouble is that if I use @ then I get double \ which mess up the RTF, and if i dont use them, then the escape charatures mess up the code??

what is the best way to build up this string by adding a preformated RTF header and the aray of strings in the middle. it is displayed finaly in a RTF.textbox. or converted to a plain text string at the users request. I need to ignore the escape charatures with out messing up the RTF?

Cheers

Aaron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't get a double `\`.  You're getting confuzzled by the debugger display of the string.  It shows you what the string looks like if you had written it in C# without the @.  Click the spy glass icon at the far right and select the Text Visualizer.

Comment: Confuzzled? Mary and Max? http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0978762/quotes?qt=qt1025504

Comment: Doh!! cheers Hans I jsut saw that as i was poking around. :) It was the first RTF line config = @"\rtf1\ansi\deff0\deftab240 ............. I missed the leading { off!! DOH!!